# Scala: Detect and extract something more specific from a collection of `Any` values

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, saddle

Scala: Detect and extract something more specific from a collection of `Any` values.

(Motivation: The [Saddle library](https://saddle.github.io/) -- the only Scala library I have found that provides a Frame type, which is critical for data science -- leads me to this puzzle. See last section for details.)

## The problem

Imagine a collection `c` of type `C[Any]`. Suppose that some of the elements of `c` are of a type `T` which is strictly more specific than `Any`.

I would like a way to find all the elements of type `T`, and to then create an object `d` of type `C[T]`, rather than `C[Any]`.

## Some code demonstrating the problem

```scala
scala> val c  = List(0,1,"2","3")
<console>:11: warning: a type was inferred to be `Any`;
this may indicate a programming error.
       val c  = List(0,1,"2","3")
                ^
c: List[Any] = List(0, 1, 2, 3)

scala> :t c(0)
Any // I wish this were more specific

// Scala can convert some elements to Int.
scala> val c0 = c(0) . asInstanceOf[Int]
c0: Int = 0
// But how would I detect which?

scala> val d = c.slice(0,2)
d: List[Any] = List(0, 1) // I wish this were List[Int]
```

## Motivation: Why the Saddle library leads me to this problem

Saddle lets you manipulate "Frames" (tables). Frames can have columns of various types. Some systems (e.g. Pandas) assign a separate type to each column. Every Frame in Saddle, however, has exactly three type parameters: The type of row labels, the type of column labels, and the type of cells.

Real world data is typically a mix of strings and numbers. The way such tables are represented in Saddle is as a Frame with a cell type of Any. I'd like to downcast (upcast? [polymorphism is hard](https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/polymorphic_types)) a column to something more specific than a Series of Any values. I'd also like to be able to test a column, to be sure that the cast is appropriate.

I posted an [issue on Saddle's Github site](https://github.com/saddle/saddle/issues/86) about the puzzle.

Comment: In general this is not possible, and it usually means a design error. I would start by checking if your are using the **library** as intended or if you can use other library. - Anyways, for simple types you can do this: `def extract[T : ClassTag](list: List[Any]): List[T] = list.collect { case t: T => t }` and you can call it like this: `extract[Int](c)` _(if you want, you can codify this as a **extension method**)_. But, keep in mind that for complex types like `extract[List[String]]` it will fail.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Comments are for notes and queries about the question itself. Answers like this should really go in an Answer not a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
scala> val c  = List(0,1,"2","3")
c: List[Any] = List(0, 1, 2, 3)
scala> c.collect { case x: Int => x; case s: String => s.toInt  }
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

If you just want the `Int` types you can simply drop the second case.